# foreach seletivo duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

me ajudem por favor, sou iniciante.

Bom, eu estou com um site com codeigniter, ele está mostrando
minhas receitas perfeitamente no:

```
<?php foreach ($receitas as $receita) :?>
```

Agora quero criar um loop que só mostra as receitas que estão nos favoritos, que no caso é uma outra tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

preciso que ele recupere todas as id_receita do usuario logado, no caso o 35, e o loop acima mostre todas elas, sem mostras as outras não salvas.

mais informações caso precisem:

CONTROLLER

```
public function favoritos(){

    $this->load->model("Receitas_model");
    $lista = $this->Receitas_model->buscaTodos();
    $dados = array ("receitas" => $lista);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('receitas/favoritos', $dados);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

MODEL

```
public function buscaTodos(){
    $this->db->order_by('criado','desc');
    return  $this->db->get("receitas")->result_array();     
}
```

O usuário logado pode ter várias receitas salvas como favorita, e preciso mostrar somente essas salvas, não quero mostrar todas.

Comment: Seja bem vindo @Gabriel Ichikawa Craice! Adicione a sua pergunta mais informações sobre a outra tabela `favoritos`, e também o que você já tentou para solucionar o problema. Mas já adiantando, com as informações que colocou, parece que apenas você deve adicionar um `INNER JOIN` na sua consulta lincando a sua tabela `favoritos`.

Comment: Olá @8bit , primeiro obrigado pela resposta.
eu coloquei a imagem do formato da tabela favoritos,,
ela contem somente " ID (int) , id_usuario(int) , id_receita(int) "

ela somente armazena as informações de quando um usuário adiciona uma determinada receita aos favoritos, obviamente o mesmo usuário pode ter várias receitas salvas, e preciso mostrar isso, todas as receitas salvas pelo usuário X.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, consegui seguindo o conselho do @8biT , código abaixo:

```
public function buscaTodos3(){
    $usuarioID = $this->session->userdata('usuario_logado')['id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM receitas 
    INNER JOIN favoritos 
    ON favoritos.id_receita = receitas.id
    WHERE id_usuario = '$usuarioID'";

    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return  $result->result_array();        
}
```

Comment: Ótimo, que bom que conseguiu!